# Make the readers [supervisor] understand the effort I put on data construction in an academically sound way

Tags: thesis, advisor, data

In my Master thesis I use an alternative database, namely histdata.com which provides free tick by tick data (kinda rough data that need a lot of coding to be transformed but free). To the best of my knowledge this is the first time somebody has ever employed data from this database on a official paper. Usually tick data are purchased from independent providers for thousands of dollars/euros. Should I explicitly mention the fact that I used a free database data and my efforts to transform the data in a working form? Essentially I saved my self from a potentially heavy cost through some free data and heavy coding.

Comment: It would seem pretty clear that you have to cite the source of your data. How you transformed it might or might not be relevant, depending on whether it is a creative part of your methods, or just a routine chore.

Comment: Of course I am going to mention the data source, like [data are taken from _.com and span form _ to _]. I am just trying to find a way to explicitly say that is a new databse beyong the consensus and significant work has been applied to derive the final functional form of the data. @NateEldredge

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are running into the age-old problem that, in research, you are reporting on results, not effort. Your paper (or thesis) is not a time sheet that needs to accurately reflect how much time went into which activity, but it should discuss your approach, results, and conclusions.

Hence, making your supervisor **understand the effort [you] put on data construction** is not a sound goal for a formal paper. I am not saying that your supervisor should not know how you spend your time, but this is an item for face-to-face discussion, not your thesis. Describe the data source, describe its properties (and, as a sidenote, I would not focus on the "it's free" aspect, but comment more on the quality of the data set), and describe the necessary transformations *if they are interesting* (instead of straight-forward but tedious, which most transformations seem to be).